# .NET / C# Issue - Assigning a Mouse Event Handler To A Hyperlink

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, web-applications

In my default.aspx I have the following:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<h1>Database Exercise - Branches/Staff</h1>
<p>Type a message to store</p>
<input type="text" name="texth" />
<a id ="submit" onclick="Submit_Message()">Submit</a>
</asp:Content>
```

In my Default.aspx.cs I have

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        //test event handler - submit message
        protected void Submit_Message(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.Write("Hello");
        }
    }
}
```

Upon running the application I get:

**Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'Submit_Message' is undefined**

All I want is for the Submit_Message() event handler to fire when the link is pressed....What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<a id ="submit" onclick="Submit_Message()">Submit</a>` is handled completely client side, it is never handled by the server, so onclick refers to a JavaScript method called Submit_Message.

If you want a link that fires an event on the server side, use `<asp:LinkButton .../>` instead:

```
<asp:LinkButton id="submit" runat="server" OnClick="Submit_Message" Text="Submit" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to call a Server-Side Method, by calling a Javascript-function, so you're mixing Client side and Server side.

You can use a ASP:LinkButton in the view, and put the onclick-event in there:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton" runat="server" onclick="Submit_Message">Link</asp:LinkButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call a server side event handler from a client side onclick event.

You need to use ASP control, such as `LinkButton`, which will render a standard anchor element (`<a>`) to the client, with `runat=server` attribute and bind its `OnClick` server side event to the code behind handler as this:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="Submit_Message" />
```